# Is there 100% black theme for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? (I am talking about darkness the level of MS DOS background i.e., no light emission)

Tags: 20.04, themes, lts

I know there are infinite dark themes available over internet and I have googled it so much and tried almost all dark themes. However, no theme is having 100% black colour, it is always a shade of black (emitting some amount of light) not pitch black or perfectly black. Even in the pitch black coloured theme or high contrast theme, it is only a shade of black, it still emits light like dark grey colour but not absence of light. What I am referring to is the **colour in MS DOS background** for example. That 100% dark colour theme is available nowhere. Now I think that may be the minimum can be done is somehow change any existing dark them to that colour by some system modification (I do not know how but I wish to know) or the better still if someone knows such a theme, please share link with me. I will thank you very much for this help. Thanks.

Edit. For a reference I am posting this sample dark terminal screenshot. This is only a example screenshot, original dark/black will look exactly like background of MS DOS.

[image]

**Edit:**
Some users have asked me to try Kubuntu KDE, but this does not answer the question. Reason: What KDE offers, Ubuntu also offers. I am attaching a screenshot of Orchis them which I am currently using and is giving equal or more darkness than KDE. But it is not near to what I am seeking in the question. The question is very clear on this. I have also attached screenshot of the reference colour above. And here is what I have been able to achieve till now:
[image]

P.S. This is a potentially challenging & interesting question. :)

Comment: [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/enable-full-dark-mode-in-ubuntu-20-04) any help?

Comment: I tried that the very first thing. It emits light. For a reference I am posting the colour reference: https://i.postimg.cc/3NNQk5RF/Screenshot-from-2021-01-12-02-02-17.png           I am also editing the question now with reference colour example from screen shot of terminal in total darkness. It must not emit light. Thanks.

Comment: Every color must emit light. That's how modern screens work.

Comment: The black terminal background in modern screens produce the colour desired. You may check that on your system. Thanks.

Comment: So you want *no* delineation between different widgets on the screen? ...It may be difficult to use the OS. For example, buttons may not have an outline, so you wouldn't know where to click. Ubuntu does have a High Contrast option in Settings. This setting coupled with the dark theme comes pretty close, but not 100% dark, like your example image. You can also look for themes at https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/135/order/latest/ to see if something matches what you are looking for,

Comment: Unless you have an OLED display, even pure black will be lit up because the entire screen has a backlight.

Comment: @PJ Singh Thanks for writing. Before posting this question, I tried everything you have mentioned. And I will not call it close because it is not. The theme design should inherently make the user distinguish the borders, by giving it a tinge of white or may be dark grey for example on the borders. That website, all dark themes tried, it is not pitch black. Even the theme named pitch black or high contrast is not black.

Comment: Are you willing to use KDE (Kubuntu) or it *has* to be Gnome shell ?

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for input. The dark terminal is able to produce the 100% black effect of like MS DOS background does. They did not have OLED display or neither mine may have one but still it is able to produce that color that means it is possible but no one has done it perhaps.

Comment: @PJ Singh Does KDE desktop offer that? I pretty much doubt it because all dark themes I tried, no one came close to the dark terminal background. I will prefer this existing desktop because I have spent a lot of time modifying this. It would be tough for me to migrate. Thanks. :)

Comment: You can always install KDE desktop in your current installation. Then select KDE from the login screen. However, I suggest trying this out using a live USB (or Live *.iso in VirtualBox) to make sure you have the level of control you want. If you are happy with what you can achieve, you can then install the "K Desktop Environment" using `sudo apt install kde-full`.

Comment: I have edited the question now. What KDE has achieved, I was able to get that from Ubuntu also. Thanks. :) But MS DOS type background is not achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Try Kubuntu (KDE)...

You have a great deal of control over every aspect of the UI.

Here are screenshots of the process in Kubuntu 19.10...

1. Open System Settings.
2. Select Colors option.
3. Select the theme you want to edit, and click the "pencil" icon.
   [image: System Settings]
4. Select the UI component you want to change.
   [image: Edit Theme]
5. Select the new color.
   [image: Select Colors]

Answer (score 1):

> However, no theme is having 100% black colour, it is always a shade of black (emitting some amount of light) not pitch black or perfectly black. Even in the pitch black coloured theme or high contrast theme, it is only a shade of black, it still emits light like dark grey colour but not absence of light.

Even with an MS DOS background with {Hue, Val, Sat, R, G, B} = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} i.e. "perfect black" as color, you'll still have light emissions as typical monitor panels have backlight.

To really obtain no light emission for black, use an OLED monitor.

Comment: Ubuntu terminal, also MS DOS is able to produce the dark black color on all monitors without OLED display, how is that black color achieved? It means it can be done on themes as well. Is there theme with that black color?

Comment: I would:
1. Open up the terminal (i.e. MS CMD) with the target black color (or any app with the black color which satisfies your preference); 
2. Printscreen → Paste on MS Paint; 
3. Use color picker and take note of the Hue/ Val/ Sat/ R/ G/ B values; 
4. Use that color on the theme

Comment: One request. The step 4, is use that colour on the theme. How can we do that?

Comment: Same as PJ Singh's steps above ^

Answer (score 0):

If you want no light emission like MS-DOS, use a plain terminal, because that's what MS-DOS used. You can have that by entering a tty session, no GUI with mouse pointer, bells and whistles, by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F3 at your login screen. You will be asked to login by entering your username and password, and then use it like any regular terminal.

Other than this, there is no theme that is perfectly dark. This is also not perfectly dark too, as you are still seeing the text with green/white fonts.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully someone will create this type of theme soon where other colors are there but black is taken to highest level of darkness possible by monitor. I tried using greyscale but in it many a times I am unable to distinguish between options, because greyscale converts everything to different shades of black and often different colours to same shade of grey. So what happens is different coloured options may appear as a same shade of grey as governed by greyscale. If you may ever come to know of existence of such a theme, please do post a link. Thank you.

Comment: I have also heard of a theme called Material-Black. It was the blackest theme I ever saw on a GUI, yes not tty

Comment: I tried it now and it is slightly darker than Orchis theme which I was using before. Although not near to CMD black, but I will keep this for now until a pure black theme is made. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a lot of search, I have found something near to what I was looking for. However, there is still scope for improvement in this theme.

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1385685/

In spite of being a beautiful theme, there are low ratings. I believe this is because it is not visible to users when we browse for themes from tweaks->appearance->themes despite saving theme in user/share/themes folder. I installed it using appimagelauncher and Pling-store. I am keeping this question open because I believe a still better answer may be possible.

Edit: This theme is very close now:
https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1235254/
(WatchOS theme of Mac - simply great)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dark theme in Ubuntu, change it to transparent and change the wallpaper to this:

[image: Complete darkness]